# How to create a single producer?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I have a message list coming from API, I need to map the elements in this list, send them to the producer and read them one by one.
Multiple users can send message lists at the same time.
I need to map the lists in order and not read the other list before one list is completely finished.
Since a new producer is created for each request in the current structure, I cannot read the incoming messages sequentially.
How can I do this by creating a single producer?

```
public class MailController : BaseController
    {
        [HttpPost("fatura")]
        //[AllowAnonymous]
        public bool fatura([FromBody] List<MailMessage> mailMessages)
        {
            FaturaProducer.Produce(mailMessages);
            return default;
        }
}
```

---

```
public class FaturaProducer : FProducer<MailMessage>
    {
        public static Task Produce(List<MailMessage> data)
        {
           Produce(ConfigurationManager.KafkaSettings.Topics[Topics.FaturaKaydetViaTp].TopicName, data);
           return default;
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class FProducer<T> : ProducerBase2
    {
        private static readonly ObjectSerializer<T> serializer = new ObjectSerializer<T>();
        //public static IProducer<Null, T> producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, T>(producerConfig).SetValueSerializer(serializer).Build();
        public static async Task<DeliveryResult<Null, T>> Produce(string topic,List<T> data)
        {
            try
            {
                LogManager.Logger.Debug("Producer initiating for {topic}", topic);

                using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, T>(producerConfig).SetValueSerializer(serializer).Build())
                {
                    LogManager.Logger.Debug("Producer initiated");

                    LogManager.Logger.Debug("Producing async");

                    try
                    {
                        foreach (var item in data)
                        {
                            producer.Poll(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                            await producer.ProduceAsync(topic, new Message<Null, T> { Value = item });
                        }
                       
                    }
                    catch (ProduceException<Null, string> ex)
                    {
                        LogManager.Logger.Fatal(ex, "Delivery failed: {reason}", ex.Error.Reason);
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogManager.Logger.Fatal(ex, "Producer failed for {topic}", topic);
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you're looping over the list, calling your Produce function, and creating one producer for *each and every message*

Alternatively, make a new Produce method that *accepts the whole list*, then wrap your foreach loop with `using (var producer` block so that only one producer is used for all messages, keeping in mind that you should not `return` on the very first loop item. You're not doing anything with the DeliveryResult, anyway, so make the method be void.

Comment: I tried to send a list to the producer, but every time I make a request, a new producer is created, how can I single it out?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that. But if you must, you'd need to create a producer object at the very start of your application, as a static singleton, and self-manage it rather than with a using statement around only code sections that need it